# Python- appending coordinate-like string into list

Tags: python, algorithm

I am attempting to append a coordinate-like value into a list. the following is my code so far, but it returns `["(0,1),(1,1),(1,2)"]` when I need it to return `[(0,1),(1,1),(1,2)]`.

```
def read_coords(s):
    coords_s = []
    row = 0
    split_coords = s.split('\n')
    for i in split_coords:
        i = list(i)
        for z in range(len(i)):
            indiv_coord = []
            if i[z] == 'O':
                coords_s.append('('+str(row)+','+str(z)+')')
                row += 1            
    return coords_s
```

The test cases I am using are:

`read_coords("O..\n.OO\n")` which should return --> `[(0,0), (1,1), (1,2)]`
o `read_coords("\n\nO..\n.OO\n\n")` → `[(0,0),  (1,1),  (1,2)]

## ignores blank lines.

`read_coords(".....\n.....\n")` → `[]`

Comment: Can you explain how the input of "0..\n.00\n" returns (0,0), (1,1),(1,2)? (or could you provide a complete input line?)

Comment: @Back2Basics apologies, the input "O..\n.OO\n" is basically creating a 3x3 grid. wherever there is an 'O', a coordinate must be returned corresponding to its position on the grid.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't creating the data structure you think you are.

This line you have here:

```
coords_s.append('('+str(row)+','+str(z)+')')
```

What you are doing there is actually appending a string to your list as "(row, z)".

The structure you are referring to is called a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

You should be changing your code to actually append the tuple to your list, and the type-casting to `str` is most likely unnecessary either. So, you can simply do this:

```
coords_s.append((row, z))
```

Comment: wouldnt that just return [('0', '0'), ('1', '1'), ('2', '2')] ? could I then use something like ''.join(coords_s) ?

Comment: Correct, the solution I provided would give you an output as: `[('0', '0'), ('1', '1'), ('2', '2')]`. `''.join(coords_s)` will create a string out of your list. You don't want that based on the example you provided.

Comment: Why use `str` at all? Why not just the tuple `coords_s.append(row, z)`?  Bottom line to all of this, go read up on 'tuples' in the python docs.

Comment: That is true @RobertB . I tried sticking with OP structure as much as possible, but it really looks like it shouldn't be there. I removed it from my solution. Cheers.

Comment: And you did it correctly versus what I typed, oops.

Comment: @RobertB :) I didn't even notice you wrote it incorrectly until you mentioned it. :P